# ActiveRecord NullDB adapter not loading tables/columns

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, database-connection

I am trying to use the NullDB database adapter to create/run specs for an external database. As I dont want to query the external database for the specs I want to use NullDB instead.

The Problem is: I created a seperate `schema.rb` file that should be used by nulldb, set nulldb as adapter and the `schema.rb` path in my config for the test env, but, my models dont have columns, therefore methods like `name=` are also failing.

NullDb reads out the schema correct and also creates tables with the columns.

```
NullDBNamespace::Product.columns
   (4.2ms)  DROP TABLE "products"
   (9.8ms)  CREATE TABLE "products" ("id" serial primary key, "products_id" integer, "products_model" integer, "products_master" integer, "manufacturers_id" integer, "products_tax_class_id" integer, "products_quantity" integer, "products_evp" decimal(16,8), "products_ean" character varying) 
   (3.1ms)  DROP TABLE "descriptions"
   (7.1ms)  CREATE TABLE "descriptions" ("id" serial primary key, "products_id" integer, "language_id" integer, "products_name" character varying, "products_description" text) 
   (3.1ms)  DROP TABLE "languages"
   (5.9ms)  CREATE TABLE "languages" ("id" serial primary key, "languages_id" integer, "name" character varying, "code" character varying)
```

but I get

```
NullDBNamespace::Product.columns
=> []
```

also there are no tables for the connection:

```
NullDBNamespace::Product.connection.tables
=> ["schema_info"]
```

Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: @vjdhama: thx for editing

Comment: It seems like that the problem is caused by having two different database connections. One is used for the apps internal tables (uses `postgresql`) and then there are a few tables that should use the nulldb adapter.

Comment: In that case you need to specify the connections for the model there are a lot of tutorials on how to do this but I generally create an abstract class to handle this and then inherit from the abstract class for the NullDB models.

Comment: i already have a concern that establishes the connection for the nullDb models seperatly. but it seems that nullDb is not made for that case as it seems that it always tries to use ActiveRecord::Base.connection instead of the model specific one...

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. To handle models with multiple databases I generally set up the most frequent database as models that inherit from ActiveRecord::Base. Then the extraneous models will inherit from a class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base e.g. `class Connection < ActiveRecord::Base; self.abstract_class = true; establish_connection (:adapter => :nulldb,:schema  => 'foo/myschema.rb'); end;` now all the models that need to use NullDb should inherit from `Connection` not `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice, i'll try that...

Comment: @FlorianEck, did you manage to solve this? I'm having exactly the same issue. I'm connecting an abstract model to a :nulldb adapter and loading the respective schema file but the only table it can find is ["schema_info"].